# How to add menu to cart in flutter and passing data from menu page to cart page?

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart

I have a problem when doing add to cart, the data in the API was sent successfully but on the cart page the data is null, am I wrong with the logic? please let me know, thank you

[Null Value Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kOhU.png)  [For Response API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZuZq.png)

For CartModel

```
class CartModel {
  int? id;
  MenuModel? menu;
  int? quantity;

  CartModel({
    this.id,
    this.menu,
    this.quantity,
  });

  CartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    menu = MenuModel.fromJson(json['menu']);
    quantity = json['quantity'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'menu': menu!.toJson(),
      'quantity': quantity,
    };
  }

  getTotalPrice() {
    return menu!.menuPrice! * quantity!;
  }
}
```

For CheckoutModel

```
class CheckoutModel {
  List<CartOrders>? cartOrders;
  EcoBag? ecoBag;
  int? subtotal;
  int? multiplier;
  Delivery? delivery;
  Outlet? outlet;
  int? deliveryFee;
  int? freeDelivery;
  int? totalDeliveryFee;
  int? promo;
  int? useJpoint;
  JpointInfo? jpointInfo;
  int? grandtotal;
  Error? error;
  List<Null>? invalidMenu;

  CheckoutModel({
    this.cartOrders,
    this.ecoBag,
    this.subtotal,
    this.multiplier,
    this.delivery,
    this.outlet,
    this.deliveryFee,
    this.freeDelivery,
    this.totalDeliveryFee,
    this.promo,
    this.useJpoint,
    this.jpointInfo,
    this.grandtotal,
    this.error,
    this.invalidMenu,
  });

  CheckoutModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['cart_orders'] != null) {
      cartOrders = <CartOrders>[];
      json['cart_orders'].forEach((v) {
        cartOrders!.add(CartOrders.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    ecoBag = json['ecoBag'] != null ? EcoBag.fromJson(json['ecoBag']) : null;
    subtotal = json['subtotal'];
    multiplier = json['multiplier'];
    delivery =
        json['delivery'] != null ? Delivery.fromJson(json['delivery']) : null;
    outlet = json['outlet'] != null ? Outlet.fromJson(json['outlet']) : null;
    deliveryFee = json['delivery_fee'];
    freeDelivery = json['freeDelivery'];
    totalDeliveryFee = json['total_delivery_fee'];
    promo = json['promo'];
    useJpoint = json['use_jpoint'];
    jpointInfo = json['jpoint_info'] != null
        ? JpointInfo.fromJson(json['jpoint_info'])
        : null;
    grandtotal = json['grandtotal'];
    error = json['error'] != null ? Error.fromJson(json['error']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (cartOrders != null) {
      data['cart_orders'] = cartOrders!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (ecoBag != null) {
      data['ecoBag'] = ecoBag!.toJson();
    }
    data['subtotal'] = subtotal;
    data['multiplier'] = multiplier;
    if (delivery != null) {
      data['delivery'] = delivery!.toJson();
    }
    if (outlet != null) {
      data['outlet'] = outlet!.toJson();
    }
    data['delivery_fee'] = deliveryFee;
    data['freeDelivery'] = freeDelivery;
    data['total_delivery_fee'] = totalDeliveryFee;
    data['promo'] = promo;
    data['use_jpoint'] = useJpoint;
    if (jpointInfo != null) {
      data['jpoint_info'] = jpointInfo!.toJson();
    }
    data['grandtotal'] = grandtotal;
    if (error != null) {
      data['error'] = error!.toJson();
    }

    return data;
  }
}

class CartOrders {
  String? menuCode;
  String? menuName;
  String? menuImage;
  int? menuQuantity;
  int? menuPrice;
  int? subTotal;
  String? menuDetail;

  CartOrders(
      {this.menuCode,
      this.menuName,
      this.menuImage,
      this.menuQuantity,
      this.menuPrice,
      this.subTotal,
      this.menuDetail});

  CartOrders.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    menuCode = json['menu_code'];
    menuName = json['menu_name'];
    menuImage = json['menu_image'];
    menuQuantity = json['menu_quantity'];
    menuPrice = json['menu_price'];
    subTotal = json['sub_total'];
    menuDetail = json['menu_detail'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['menu_code'] = menuCode;
    data['menu_name'] = menuName;
    data['menu_image'] = menuImage;
    data['menu_quantity'] = menuQuantity;
    data['menu_price'] = menuPrice;
    data['sub_total'] = subTotal;
    data['menu_detail'] = menuDetail;
    return data;
  }
}

class EcoBag {
  String? ecobagCode;
  String? ecobagName;
  int? ecobagQuantity;
  int? ecobagPrice;
  int? ecobagSubtotalNormal;
  int? ecobagSubtotal;

  EcoBag(
      {this.ecobagCode,
      this.ecobagName,
      this.ecobagQuantity,
      this.ecobagPrice,
      this.ecobagSubtotalNormal,
      this.ecobagSubtotal});

  EcoBag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    ecobagCode = json['ecobag_code'];
    ecobagName = json['ecobag_name'];
    ecobagQuantity = json['ecobag_quantity'];
    ecobagPrice = json['ecobag_price'];
    ecobagSubtotalNormal = json['ecobag_subtotal_normal'];
    ecobagSubtotal = json['ecobag_subtotal'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['ecobag_code'] = ecobagCode;
    data['ecobag_name'] = ecobagName;
    data['ecobag_quantity'] = ecobagQuantity;
    data['ecobag_price'] = ecobagPrice;
    data['ecobag_subtotal_normal'] = ecobagSubtotalNormal;
    data['ecobag_subtotal'] = ecobagSubtotal;
    return data;
  }
}

class Delivery {
  int? typeId;
  String? type;
  String? service;
  EstimatedTimeline? estimatedTimeline;
  double? distance;

  Delivery(
      {this.typeId,
      this.type,
      this.service,
      this.estimatedTimeline,
      this.distance});

  Delivery.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    typeId = json['type_id'];
    type = json['type'];
    service = json['service'];
    estimatedTimeline = json['estimatedTimeline'] != null
        ? EstimatedTimeline.fromJson(json['estimatedTimeline'])
        : null;
    distance = json['distance'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['type_id'] = typeId;
    data['type'] = type;
    data['service'] = service;
    if (estimatedTimeline != null) {
      data['estimatedTimeline'] = estimatedTimeline!.toJson();
    }
    data['distance'] = distance;
    return data;
  }
}

class EstimatedTimeline {
  String? pickup;
  String? dropoff;

  EstimatedTimeline({this.pickup, this.dropoff});

  EstimatedTimeline.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    pickup = json['pickup'];
    dropoff = json['dropoff'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['pickup'] = pickup;
    data['dropoff'] = dropoff;
    return data;
  }
}

class Outlet {
  List<Reference>? reference;
  Reference? selected;

  Outlet({this.reference, this.selected});

  Outlet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['reference'] != null) {
      reference = <Reference>[];
      json['reference'].forEach((v) {
        reference!.add(Reference.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    selected =
        json['selected'] != null ? Reference.fromJson(json['selected']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (reference != null) {
      data['reference'] = reference!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (selected != null) {
      data['selected'] = selected!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Reference {
  String? outletId;
  String? outletCode;
  String? outletTimezone;
  String? outletLatitude;
  String? outletLongitude;
  double? distance;

  Reference(
      {this.outletId,
      this.outletCode,
      this.outletTimezone,
      this.outletLatitude,
      this.outletLongitude,
      this.distance});

  Reference.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    outletId = json['outlet_id'];
    outletCode = json['outlet_code'];
    outletTimezone = json['outlet_timezone'];
    outletLatitude = json['outlet_latitude'];
    outletLongitude = json['outlet_longitude'];
    distance = double.tryParse(json['distance'].toString());
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['outlet_id'] = outletId;
    data['outlet_code'] = outletCode;
    data['outlet_timezone'] = outletTimezone;
    data['outlet_latitude'] = outletLatitude;
    data['outlet_longitude'] = outletLongitude;
    data['distance'] = distance;
    return data;
  }
}

class JpointInfo {
  int? jpointBalance;
  int? jpointUsed;
  int? jpointEarn;
  int? jpointFinalBalance;

  JpointInfo(
      {this.jpointBalance,
      this.jpointUsed,
      this.jpointEarn,
      this.jpointFinalBalance});

  JpointInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    jpointBalance = json['jpoint_balance'];
    jpointUsed = json['jpoint_used'];
    jpointEarn = json['jpoint_earn'];
    jpointFinalBalance = json['jpoint_final_balance'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['jpoint_balance'] = jpointBalance;
    data['jpoint_used'] = jpointUsed;
    data['jpoint_earn'] = jpointEarn;
    data['jpoint_final_balance'] = jpointFinalBalance;
    return data;
  }
}

class Error {
  String? type;
  String? message;
  String? couponCode;

  Error({this.type, this.message, this.couponCode});

  Error.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type = json['type'];
    message = json['message'];
    couponCode = json['coupon_code'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['type'] = type;
    data['message'] = message;
    data['coupon_code'] = couponCode;
    return data;
  }
}
```

For Cart Provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jco_donuts_app/model/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:jco_donuts_app/model/menu_model.dart';

class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<CartModel> _carts = [];

  List<CartModel> get carts => _carts;

  set carts(List<CartModel> carts) {
    _carts = carts;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addCart(MenuModel menu) {
    if (menuExist(menu)) {
      int index = _carts
          .indexWhere((element) => element.menu!.menuCode == menu.menuCode);
      _carts[index].quantity = _carts[index].quantity! + 1;
    } else {
      _carts.add(CartModel(
        id: _carts.length,
        menu: menu,
        quantity: 1,
      ));
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  removeCart(int id) {
    _carts.removeAt(id);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addQuantity(int id) {
    _carts[id].quantity = _carts[id].quantity! + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  reduceQuantity(int id) {
    _carts[id].quantity = _carts[id].quantity! - 1;
    if (_carts[id].quantity == 0) {
      removeCart(id);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  totalItems() {
    int total = 0;
    for (var item in _carts) {
      total += item.quantity!;
    }
    return total;
  }

  totalPrice() {
    int total = 0;
    for (var item in _carts) {
      total += (item.quantity! * item.menu!.menuPrice!);
    }
    return total;
  }

  menuExist(MenuModel menu) {
    if (_carts
            .indexWhere((element) => element.menu!.menuCode == menu.menuCode) ==
        -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

For Checkout(Transaction) Provider

```
class TransactionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  CheckoutModel? _checkoutModel;

  CheckoutModel? get checkoutModel => _checkoutModel;
  set checkoutModel(CheckoutModel? checkoutModel) {
    _checkoutModel = checkoutModel;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> checkout(List<CartModel> cart) async {
    try {
      await TransanctionService().checkout(
        cart,
      );
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      // print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

For Checkout(Transaction Service)

```
 Future<CheckoutModel> checkout(List<CartModel> carts) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/v1/checkout/get');
    String? accessToken = await storage.read(key: 'accessToken');
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    };
    var body = jsonEncode({
      "order_city": "Jakarta Barat",
      "coupon_code": "",
      "order_payment": "bca_va",
      "delivery_type": 0,
      "order_brand": "JCO",
      "cart_info": carts
          .map((carts) => {
                'menu_code': carts.menu?.menuCode,
                'menu_quantity': carts.quantity,
                'menu_detail': '',
              })
          .toList(),
      "use_jpoint": 0,
      "order_address":
          "Jalan Meruya Selatan No.68, RT.5/RW.1, Meruya Selatan, Kota Jakarta Barat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta, Indonesia",
      "order_address_info": "",
      "order_latitude": "-6.20395670",
      "order_longitude": "106.73864490"
    });

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );

    print(body);
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      CheckoutModel checkoutModel = CheckoutModel.fromJson(data['data']);
      return checkoutModel;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```

For Button Add to Cart

```
// Buttons
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                defaultMargin,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 54,
                    height: 54,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        wishlistProvider.setMenu(widget.menu);

                        if (wishlistProvider.isWishlist(widget.menu)) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff50d890),
                              content: Text(
                                'Has been add to the Wishlist',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              backgroundColor: alertColor,
                              content: const Text(
                                'Has been remove from the Wishlist',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
```

I try to adding transaction provider but still not effect